# Pixels difference between Firefox and online tools

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Our responsive design is based on Firefox inbuilt responsive tool and Chrome responsive for cross-validation.

But when we tested same configurations on online responsive tools, I had to adjust 16px margin to get a similar result as Firefox.

I am puzzled as to why there is a difference and which tool to believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Relative units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) are highly recommended for a responsive website.

It's important to realize that web pages will always render differently in different browsers. Achieving pixel perfection is futile, and nowadays I try to explain to my clients what kind of cost is involved to make every browser render the site exactly alike.